# How can I simulate a button click given the handle to the button's window?

Tags: c++, winapi, button

I want to simulate a click on a button located in a dialog box.

I have the handle to that window. This is an Abort/Retry/Ignore kind of window.

I don't want to go with simulating a click having X and Y coordinates as it doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: Could this be of help?
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?377394-Windows-SDK-User-Interface-How-can-I-emulate-mouse-events-in-an-application

Comment: It is not normal. Seems that assert fails somewhere and you are running debug version. Try _set_abort_behavior().

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Find the handle to the button that you want to click (by using `FindWindowEx`), and just send click message:

```
SendMessage(hButton, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(0, 0));
SendMessage(hButton, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(0, 0));
```

Comment: It works but it's not an ellegant solution. Doesn't WinAPI support functions that would directly "click" one of the windows's buttons? And I had to use Spy++ to get the name of the Button which wasn't straight-forward.

Comment: @AronBoguta You can enumerate all windows using `EnumChildWindows`, until you find out target button handle. If WinAPI contained a function that would directly "click" on of the window's buttons, it would do exactly the same that we did. Also, WinAPI is treating buttons as (child) windows.

Comment: thanks, I know already about the EnumChildWindows still I would expect more from WinAPI :)

Comment: @AronBoguta: Use a single `BM_CLICK` message instead of two `WM_LBUTTON...` messages: `SendMessage(hButton, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 19):

Send a `BM_CLICK` message to the HWND of the button:

```
SendMessage(hButton, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
```

That causes the button to receive `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` messages, and the parent to receive an `BN_CLICKED` notification, as if the user had physically clicked on the button.

Answer (score 12):

```
SendMessage(hParent, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IdOfButton, BN_CLICKED), (LPARAM)hwndOfButton);
```

Typically you can get away without the `hwndOfButton`, if you don't know it - depends on the dialog's implementation!

It can be `SendMessage` or `PostMessage`, depending on your use case.

Comment: Tried all the other answers. This one is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: You do realize that in `WinUser.h`, `BN_CLICKED` is defined as follows: `#define BN_CLICKED 0`, so the `MAKEWPARAM` is superfluous here.  `WPARAM(idOfButton)` is all you need for a `WM_COMMAND` that resulted from a mouse click, unless you are trying to document in the code.

Comment: Sure, but the intent very clear if you use the #define - much better practice, much clearer code and easier to edit (to a different code). Appreciate you pointing it out though :)

Comment: This worked for me too: `SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IDC_BUTTON_MODIFY_TALK, BN_CLICKED), (LPARAM)m_btnModify.GetSafeHwnd());`

Answer (score 3):

Try this for OK:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, 1, NULL);
```

Comment: There is no OK button. Only Abort/Retry/Ignore like I said and I wish to click Abort

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete function:

```
void clickControl(HWND hWnd, int x, int y)
{
    POINT p;
    p.x = x; p.y = y;
    ClientToScreen(hWnd, &p);
    SetCursorPos(p.x, p.y);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
}
```

Comment: Even though this doesn't answer the original question, it helped me for what I was looking for, thanks !