# How to programmatically turn on "Display delete confirmation dialog" recycle bin properties

Tags: c++, windows, recycle-bin

My application allows user to delete files from its GUI. Every time they delete something, I want to show the OS confirmation dialog.

I use SHFileOperationW() to move files and folder to the recycle bin. But if the option "Display delete confirmation dialog" is not checked, no dialog will be shown.

Is there a way to programmatically turn on the "Display delete confirmation dialog" on Windows7 and 8?

[image]

Comment: Microsoft is making it difficult for developers to do things if the user (the owner of the system) chooses differently.

Comment: Why? the user specifically asked to NOT see the delete confirmation dialog? Is your intent to annoy?

Comment: @ChrisBecke On Windows 7, if user deletes something on a non-local drive (network shared storage, usb drive ...), that item will be deleted permanently. If that option is not checked, there will be no warning dialog. A lot of users don't even know that this option exists under the Recycle bin property. So my application needs to add a protection against accidental deletion.

Comment: Seems like you could [use a CMD command in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201631/execute-cmd-commands-using-c) to open the dialog and then [use SendMessage from the Windows API to simulate a button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295677/how-can-i-simulate-a-button-click-given-the-handle-to-the-buttons-window)

Comment: This may help: https://www.partitionwizard.com/disk-recovery/win10-confirm-delete.html